# BIND9 CatalogZone , nsupdate fail

Tags: bind

I try to setup a BIND9 server that use catalog zone.
I follow steps as [here](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01401)
Here is named.conf.options

```
root@risetdns02:/etc/bind# cat ./named.conf.options
key rndc_key { secret "1234abcd8765"; algorithm hmac-sha256; };

controls { inet 192.168.8.79 port 9953 allow { any; } keys { rndc_key; }; };

options {
          directory "/var/cache/bind";
          query-source address 192.168.8.79;
          notify-source 192.168.8.79;
          transfer-source 192.168.8.79;
          port 53;
          allow-new-zones yes;
          listen-on { 192.168.8.79; 127.0.0.1; };
          listen-on-v6 { none; };
          notify no;
          recursion no;
          allow-transfer { any; };
};

logging {
        channel default_file {
                file "/var/log/named/named.log" size 10m;
                severity debug;
                print-time yes;
                print-severity yes;
                print-category yes;
        };
        category default{ default_file; };
};



zone "catalog.example" {
          type master;
      file "catalog.example.db";
          allow-transfer { any; };
          allow-update { any;};
};
```

and here is the example.com.db zone file

```
root@risetdns02:/etc/bind# cat /var/cache/bind/example.com.db 
example.com. 3600 IN SOA . . 1 3600 3600 3600 3600
example.com. IN NS ns1.isc.org.
example.com. IN NS ns2.isc.org.
```

I did rndc like

```
rndc -k rndc.conf -y rndc_key -s 192.168.8.79 -p 9953 addzone example.com '{type primary; file "example.com.db";};'
```

My dig test got

```
root@risetdns02:/etc/bind# dig +short @127.0.0.1 example.com soa
. . 1 3600 3600 3600 3600
root@risetdns02:/etc/bind#
```

Next I try to nsupdate to add ptr record to that catalog zone.

```
root@risetdns02:/etc/bind# cat << __EOF | nsupdate
server 127.0.0.1 53
update add c5e4b4da1e5a620ddaa3635e55c3732a5b49c7f4.zones.catalog.example 3600 IN PTR example.com
send
__EOF
response to SOA query was unsuccessful
```

And the log say

```
08-Mar-2024 03:47:40.523 query-errors: debug 1: client @0x7f1e74004fa0 127.0.0.1#33260 (c5e4b4da1e5a620ddaa3635e55c3732a5b49c7f4.zones.catalog.example): query failed (zone not loaded) for c5e4b4da1e5a620ddaa3635e55c3732a5b49c7f4.zones.catalog.example/IN/SOA at query.c:5565
```

Could you please tell me hoiw to fix this problem or what to check.